Tracking message events in BizTalk 2020 stopped working
We're running BizTalk 2020, and we've got an issue with tracking events.
One day around a week ago new events suddenly stopped tracking. If I process something, and it fails, I can see appropriate records in Group Hub -> Suspended, but if there are no errors, nothing appears in Group Hub -> Tracked message events.
The only configuration change performed around that time was creation of a new isolated host. While setting up new HTTP receive, I've created new isolated host and appropriate host instance. But later I've removed it, so configuration was rolled back.
All tracking checkboxes on existing host/ports/pipelines are checked.
There're no logged errors in event viewer at all.
I'm not too familiar with this, but I performed some investigation and was able to find out that when I process something through BizTalk, few records appear in BizTalkMsgBoxDb in Spool and TrackingMessageReferences tables, and disappear soon. These records also appear in tables Tracking_Spool1 and TrackingData_1_x where x in [0..3], and it seems that all missing evens from the moment when tracking stopped working are sitting in these four tables (TrackingData_1_x).
SQL agent is enabled, job TrackedMessages_Copy_BizTalkMsgBoxDb runs every minute with no errors.
Moreover, I can see that records I've mentioned are being copied to BizTalkDTADb to Tracking_Spool1 and Tracking_Parts1. On the other hand, TrackingData_1_x in BizTalkDTADb are empty.
When I checked BizTalkDTADb.TDDS_StreamStatus I was able to see that streams are synced - every lastSeqNum for destinationId 0 and partitionId in [0..3] is equal to MIN(SeqNum) from BizTalkMsgBoxDb.dbo.TrackingData_1_x minus 1.
In my understanding, this means that data is moving from BizTalkMsgBoxDb to BizTalkDTADb incompletely/incorrectly.
Is there anything I can do to investigate why, before applying the universal solution "Just reinstall it all"?
I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

have you checked the purge job and the retention period? you can also make some SQL profiling on tracking tables within BizTalkDTADb and check what process is deleting the data

Hi Hichamveo, thanks for response!
Regarding purge job - do you mean DTA Purge and Archive (BizTalkDTADb)? It's disabled, but shouldn't it be disabled? I thought it should be disabled and its steps are being called from other jobs/procedures.
Regarding BizTalkDTADb - actually now I realize that since I don't see anything in Event tracking (not only message bodies but messages themselves) problem is not only in BizTalkDTADb - seems like not everything is being logged in BizTalkMsgBoxDb as well...am I correct?

DTA Purge and Archive job should be enabled, otherwise the size of your DTA Db will grow up and you will face perf issues. Can you ensure that you have an enabled host instance with tracking option ?

The only BizTalk SQL Agent Job that should be disabled is MessageBox_Message_Cleanup_BizTalkMsgBoxDb as it is called MessageBox_Message_ManageRefCountLog_BizTalkMsgBoxDb as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/biztalk/setup-config/sql-server-agent-jobs-biztalk
